# How to custom UISlide like ibooks style?

Tags: ios

How to custome UISlide,like ibooks style?

this is ibook's image:
[image][image]

this is iBook's style:
[image]

Comment: it seem it is `UIPageControl` object... have you tried to customise a `UIPageControl` class? why not?

Comment: well, good luck then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you?

If not, please tell me what you want to do with it:

http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=250

Comment: Thanks, also did a few +1's for you

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use this.

[ThumbnailPickerView](https://github.com/ayoy/ThumbnailPickerView)